# Using Functions In External File?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Xcode and have just gotten to the point where I am starting to build up a few files that I would like to include in future projects. Currently I am importing the file ...

```
#import "/Users/Gary/Documents/Xcode/FG_Include/FG_FloatFlip.h"
```

into my project at...

```
/Users/Gary/Documents/Xcode/mddStructure_PROJ/mddStructure.m
```

However I am getting the following error when I try to build.

```
Undefined symbols:
"_FG_FloatFlip", referenced from:
_main in mddStructure_PROJ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

I was initially thinking that importing the file would be all I needed, although now I am thinking I might need to do something extra in Xcode to use functions in this external file, maybe linking?

gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `FG_FloatFlip.h` to your Xcode project? I'm pretty sure Xcode only "finds" files added directly to the project. Try dragging the file to your Xcode window, and change it to simply `#import "FG_FloatFlip.h"`.

Comment: I did not add it to the current project, do I just need to add the *.h or the *.m too?

Comment: Yeah, every file you want to use should be added to the project. You don't need to move them to the actual project directory though; Xcode works independently of filepaths.

Comment: Thanks Chris, thats perfect, I just did not realise that I needed to add them to the project. Many thanks again.